# My networkmanager not working after booting into windows dual boot pc

Tags: networking, dual-boot, network-interface, networkmanager, parrotsec

I had a fine working dual boot pc.
But few days ago I booted jnto windows. From then on parrot os I my network manager fails.

Okay so I generally use parrot OS. And I was using it smoothly. But that day I had to boot into windows and yeah on windows everything works fine. But after that day when I rebooted to Parrot my network manager failed to load. But previously I was using windows and parrot without facing any problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide more details. You had a working dual boot pc - does this mean that you were able to boot into Windows and use the network and you were able to boot into Parrot OS and use the network? Then you booted into Windows and since then when you boot Parrot OS the network manager fails. Can you still boot into Windows and have a working network? What error messages does the network manager give you? Did something happen while you were in Windows before the Parrot OS network manager failed? These can all be useful clues in helping us help you :)

Comment: Okay so I generally use parrot OS. And I was using it smoothly. But that day I had to boot into windows and yeah on windows everything works fine. But after that day when I rebooted to Parrot my network manager failed to load. But previously I was using windows and parrot without facing any problem.

Comment: Try getting more info with: `journalctl -eu NetworkManager`. And please do not post screenshots.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.